# HEIDEGGER SCHOLARS NOMENCLATURE PUZZLING

Tags: ontology, heidegger

Heideggerian scholars keep utilizing the phrase "background practices" as a substitute or equivalent for *being*.

Background practices are things like instinctive social behavior that is hidden from your understanding such as the way you stand when you meet and greet a friend or stranger.

When you enter a cathedral, you behave in a reverential manner without knowing exactly why..

Why call these sublogical or prelogical behaviors "being"?

Why not call them implicate and intuitive social pressures? Why not culture? Why not undiscussed group pressures?

richard

Comment: do you have any quotes, or specific examples? it's very hard to understand what exactly you are talking about.

Comment: SEAN KELLY whose Youtube lectures are the basic Heidegger course keeps using the phrase "background practices' as meaning "being." How can practices or inchoate influences on your life be thought of as being?